# jQuery live function and add/remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, jquery-1.5, client-side-scripting

I'm using jquery 1.5 and I'm having an issue with the add and remove class function . Below is my code.

I'm creating a navigation with a normal, hover, and active state. The active state I want to add and remove the class.

```
  $(".class").hover(function(){
          $(this).css("background-color", "#666).css("color", "yellow");
    ), function(){ 
         $(this).css("background-img", url(image).css("color","#fff");
    ).live('click', function(){
           if($("ul.me li").hasClass("current")){
             $("ul.me li").removeClass("current");
                $(this).addClass("current");
             }
        });


<ul class="me">
   <li class="current"> item1 </li>
   <li> item1 </li>
   <li> item1 </li>
</ul>
```

Did I bind this on correctly?

Comment: You're not binding to anything.  It should be `$("selector").live()`

Comment: Did you consider upgrading to a more current version of jQuery. You'll still need a selector, but atleast you would'nt be using three year old code?

Comment: Please paste markup(html code) so we can better analyze.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `$("ul.me li").removeClass("current")` instead of `$("ul#me li").removeClass("current")`

```
$("selector").live('click', function(){
   if($("ul.me li").hasClass("current")){
     $("ul.me li").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you missing selector :-

```
$("ul.me li").live('click', function(){
   if($("ul.me li").hasClass("current")){
     $("ul#me li").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
     }
});
```

Comment: Plus he is looking for class in `ul.me li` and removing in `ul#me li`.

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating things in your script. You need to read the documentation for .css. You can not refer to an element by `$(".class")`. If you want to refer to an element type use only the name without the `.` or `#` like `$("ul")`. If you want to refer to a class use `$(".me")` and `$("#idName")` for ids. Single css command can take an array of css values to change. As I said earlier please go through css documentation. jQuery 1.6 was as close as I was able to get in jsfiddle. Here is a fiddle link. Please refer to the script and modify css values to your requirement.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VenC/)

**Note:**    If you are adding a class to li and removing on hover, add styles to the class in css rather than in js. It is cheaper.

Answer (score -1):

Just .live doesn't make sense. You need to set .live to jquery object like $('selector')